# Bug in Boto3 AWS S3 generate_presigned_url in Lambda Python 3.X with specified region?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I tried to write a python lambda function that returns a pre-signed url to put an object.

```
import os
import boto3
import json

import boto3

session = boto3.Session(region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
s3 = session.client('s3', region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])

upload_bucket = 'BUCKER_NAME'  # Replace this value with your bucket name!
URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 30000    # Specify how long the pre-signed URL will be valid for


# Main Lambda entry point
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return get_upload_url(event)

def get_upload_url(event):
    key = 'testimage.jpg' # Random filename we will use when uploading files

    # Get signed URL from S3
    s3_params = {
        'Bucket': upload_bucket,
        'Key': key,
        'Expires': URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS,
        'ContentType': 'image/jpeg' # Change this to the media type of the files you want to upload
    }

    # Get signed URL
    upload_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object',
        Params=s3_params,
        ExpiresIn=URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS
    )
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(upload_url)
    }
```

The code itself works and returns a signed URL in the format "https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/testimage.jpg?[...]"

However when using POSTMAN to try to put an object, it loads without ending.

Originally I thought it was because of my code, and after a while I wrote a NodeJS function that does the same thing:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION })
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
const uploadBucket = 'BUCKET_NAME'  // Replace this value with your bucket name!   
const URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 30000    // Specify how long the pre-signed URL will be valid for

// Main Lambda entry point
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return await getUploadURL(event)
}

const getUploadURL = async function(event) {
  const randomID = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000)
  const Key = 'testimage.jpg' // Random filename we will use when uploading files

  // Get signed URL from S3
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: uploadBucket,
    Key,
    Expires: URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg' // Change this to the media type of the files you want to upload
  }
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get signed URL
    let uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
    resolve({
      "statusCode": 200,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify(uploadURL)
    })
  })
}
```

The NodeJs version gives me a url in the format of "https://BUCKET_NAME.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage.jpg?"

The main difference between the two is the aws sub domain. When using NodeJS it gives me "BUCKET_NAME.**s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com**" and when using Python "https://BUCKET_NAME.**s3.amazonaws.com**"

When using python the region does not appear.
I tried, using the signed url generated in python to add the "s3.eu-west-1" manually and IT Works!!

Is this a bug in the AWS Boto3 python library?
as you can see, in the python code I tried to specify the region but it does not do anything.?

Any idea guys ?
I wanna solve this mystery :)

Thanks a lot in advance,

Léo

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue in us-east-1.  There are a few bugs in Github (e.g., [this](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3105) and [this](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3015)), but the proposed resolutions are inconsistent.

The workaround is to create an Internet-facing access point for the bucket and then assign the full ARN of the access point to your `upload_bucket` variable.

Please note that the Lambda will create a pre-signed URL, but it will only work if the Lambda has an appropriate permissions policy attached to its execution role.

Comment: Hi Alex :)

Thanks a lot !
The funny thing is that here it's working with the nodejs SDK :)

If I need to put a workaround I will just use the NodeJS lambda.

Lookis like I will open an issue on GitHub for that :)

Comment: Might be worth validating the [endpoint_url workaround](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3015#issuecomment-1330655947) too.

Comment: I spent about an hour yesterday trying to make the endpoint_url work in us-east-1 with no success

Comment: I tested with the endpoint_url workaround on boto3 version 1.26.68 and it generated a pre-signed PUT URL beginning `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/mykey?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&...`.

Comment: Yes, I got that too, but this URL format `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/key...` does not work in us-east-1.  It has to be `https://bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/key...`, which is also stated in the question.